# Tooltip problem - Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, tooltip

Since a few hours, I want to make a decent tooltip in JQuery. It's a Drupal-bases website.
I found [this](http://theezpzway.com/2009/3/17/jquery-plugin-ezpz-tooltip#section-10) nice looking tooltip and I tried to implement it. But with no success...

This is how my main page looks like:

```
<script src="themes/garland/js/jquery.ezpz_tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style>
        #tooltipcontent {
            display: none;        /* required */
            position: absolute;   /* required */
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: white;
            }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#record-price').ezpz_tooltip();
    });

</script>
```

And this is the other file:

```
print '<div id="part1-right-line3">';               
print '<div id="record-price">';                                                    
print uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);
print '</div>';                 
print '</div>';
```

And for some reason, it won't show me the tooltip...
Has it something to do with Drupal and it's use of JQuery or are there some mistakes in my code? Any idea's?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set a target and a content element? From http://theezpzway.com/2009/3/17/jquery-plugin-ezpz-tooltip: By convention, the target and content elements are bound together by the name of their id attribute. The convention is this: (name)-target-(unique id) will be bound to (name)-content-(unique id).

Comment: @EMI, where do I have to place this convention? In the Javascript?

Comment: There's a nice answer already posted here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94358/how-to-use-jquery-ui-tooltip-in-drupal7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use Tipsy tooltips, they are used by Drupal, Twitter, and Facebook.
There is a Drupal module for that.
http://drupal.org/project/tipsy

Comment: Can you fill the tooltip with variables you created with JavaScript? And is it supported by JQuery?

Comment: Ok, in the end, I used your tip. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [beautytips](http://drupal.org/project/beautytips) module that you might want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/tipsy nice module for tool tips.
thanks Valor

Regards,
devneel